# Should I use "#pragma GCC ..." or "#pragma clang ..." in Xcode

Tags: gcc, clang, c-preprocessor, pragma

Which of these should I use to ignore a warning?

```
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-W<warning>"
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-W<warning>"
```

Both seems to work for me, however which one is the correct to use?

Should I always use the one matching the compiler I'm using?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generally, you should prefer `#pragma GCC` in cases where the pragma is GCC-specific, or is equally applicable to GCC, Clang, and other compilers which try to be GCC-compatible (such as ICC). Use `#pragma clang` in cases where the pragma is in some way Clang-specific (such as a diagnostic option which doesn't exist in GCC).